# hosting webapplication on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, web-applications, web-hosting

i have WordPress installed in the root http://ibdaa.info 
what a need to do is to make sub-directory likee: http://ibdaa.info/app and upload my website to this sub-directory its contain (html,css,js)
i make try to just upload my site to previous link but it seem doesn't work

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide the details and also mention what have you tried till now

Comment: i edit my question is it clear now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to upload all the files present in the root folder of http://ibdaa.info to **http://ibdaa.info/app** and then change the **site_url** and the **wordpress_url** from the backend to the new url which in case is **http://ibdaa.info/app** and you will have to change the new url to point to the **/app** directory in the **.htaccess** file also.

A similar way would be to define constants in the wp-config.php file with the new url's

```
define('WP_HOME','http://ibdaa.info/app');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://ibdaa.info/app');
```

Comment: I dont need to move my wordpress website , i need to leave it where it is , what i need to do is to add a non wordpress website to that sub directory

Comment: Have you uploaded your files to that directory ? what is the issue or error you are facing ?